# How to fix this simple verbatim macro (plain TeX)?

Tags: verbatim, plain-tex

I have written a simple macro to typeset everything enclosed in angle brackets with a special font and to ignore the backslash character.

```
\catcode`\>=\active
\def>{\endgroup}
\catcode`\<=\active
\def<{\begingroup\tt\obeyspaces\frenchspacing\catcode`\\=12\relax}
\everymath{\catcode`\<=12\catcode`\>=12\relax}
\everydisplay{\catcode`\<=12\catcode`\>=12\relax}
```

It works just fine when typing direcly but fails when passed into another macro, e.g.,

```
<\TeX> % correct
\def\identity#1{#1}
\identity{<\TeX>} % incorrect, does expand for some reason

\bye
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\scantokens` (also from e-tex) to retokenize instead of `\detokenize`ing.
Then it does correctly add spaces (consecutive spaces are ignored, you can change this by doing `` \catcode`\ =\active `` after `\dospecials`).
And since it retokenizes, you can pass it to a macro.

```latex
\catcode`\<=\active
\def<#1>{{\tt\frenchspacing\def\do##1{\catcode`##1=12\relax}\dospecials\scantokens{#1}}}

<\TeX\TeX>
<\TeX \TeX>
\def\identity#1{#1}
\identity{<\TeX>}
```

Answer (score 5):

catcode changes affect how characters from a file are tokenized, but they have no effect on tokens that have already been made.

In your example `#1` is the single token `\TeX`.

This is why you can not use `\verb` in arguments in latex.

If you are not restricted to classic tex you can use `\detokenize` so this works in `pdftex` but needs `etex` for dvi version.

[image]

```
\catcode`\<=\active
\def<#1>{\begingroup\tt\obeyspaces\frenchspacing\detokenize{#1}\endgroup}
\everymath{\catcode`\<=12\relax}
\everydisplay{\catcode`\<=12\relax}

It works just fine when typing direcly but fails when passed into another macro, e.g.,

<\TeX> % correct
\def\identity#1{#1}
\identity{<\TeX>} % incorrect, does expand for some reason

\bye
```

Note you get a space here after `\TeX` as character tokens, including a final space are re-constructed from the csname.

Comment: I am using XeTeX so I have indeed access to `\detokenize`, than you! The only issue is this final space. I tried unskip but it won't work for `<\TeX\TeX>` for example

Comment: @John that is sort  of not fixable. You could do the catcode changes as well, then a top level `<.....>` would work as you had it but one in an argument would behave differently. That tends to be confusing. or as here you always tokenize then detokenize. You can clean up a bit, eg an `\unskip` before the `\endgroup` would remove the trailing space, but `< >` would then make no output, not a space.

Comment: So it seems to be as good as I can get, thank you for your help with that